# Running Java WAR file yields JSR-356 support unavailable

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, war

I recently changed the version of Spring Boot to 1.4.7-RELEASE and found that upon deploying the application to the server it won't launch, and yields following errors:

```
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: 2018-01-12 11:50:21.068:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3532ec19{/,[file:///stmp/jetty-127.0.0.1-8000-root.war-_-any-6997136337843
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
lines 817-840/1001 84%
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1441)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Jan 12 11:50:21 host java[10507]: 2018-01-12 11:50:21.068:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3532ec19{/,[file:///tmp/jetty-127.0.0.1-8000-root.war-_-any-699713633784
```

I am quite new to Spring Boot and have no idea where to look for guidance, I already looked for answers but couldn't find the right one.

Comment: That stacktrace does not look like spring-boot.  What version of Jetty are you using? and how are you starting it?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Jetty 9.3.12.v20160915. Looks like it's started with the command `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java  -server -Xms500m -Xmx2000m -Xss256k -jar jetty/jetty-distribution/start.jar  lib=/srv/api/jetty/jetty-distribution/lib/ -Dspring.config.location=server/application.properties  -Djava.io.tmpdir=tmp/ -Dehcache.disk.store.dir=tmp/cache`

Comment: That is not a valid `start.jar` usage. `lib=...` shows that you are not using jetty-distribution properly.  Use the [`jetty.base` and `jetty.home` concepts](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/startup-base-and-home.html), don't attempt work around them.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thank you for the response. Rolling back spring boot version to 1.4.2 solved the problem (1.4.7 and didn't work at all). We will have to take care of the configuration of jetty in this case.